# Copy node button in content page

Tags: 8

Is it posible to **add Copy node button** in content page or in action copy node who is secelt.

[image]

**Or here.**

[image]

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you have a code that does actual cloning a node?

Comment: No, I don't have code who clone node in new node.. I am looking for that..

Comment: Like this - https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_clone?

Comment: Exactly, somethink like that.. Is there other moduos, or this is only one..?